# Shell script using with tmux fails on zsh

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, tmux

I have following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# set -xv


tmux new-window -n 'foo' 'source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"; sleep 123' \;
```

On one machine it works perfectly, on the second I got an error:

```
sh: 1: source: not found
```

Ofcourse running command from shell works perfectly.
What is wrong? Machines have similar dot files....

Comment: I forgot to add that I am running script from zsh. Simmilar script that creates new tmux session on same machine runs without problems.

Comment: @twalberg `zsh -c 'fpp'` saves my life, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`source` is not a POSIX command. Use `.` instead.  The machine that fails is probably using `dash` as the system shell, not `bash`. The fact that `tmux` is executed *from* a `bash` script does not mean `bash` is used to execute the command given to `new-window`. `tmux` will use the system shell `/bin/sh`, so the command should not rely on non-POSIX features like the `source` synonym for `.`.

Comment: But on different machine `source` works as well. I think I have bash - how to check for sure?

Comment: @twalberg The argument to `new-window` is a shell command, not an executable. You can use shell builtins like `.`, as well as shell command lists like `. some_file; sleep 123`.